# clion error opening file no matter the fix

Tags: c++, file, clion

I am really confused as to why the "1.txt" file is not opening correctly and prompting the "ERROR" message no matter how I try to go about it. I do have a similar code that does work. However, I tried to correct my code based on that, but it just doesn't work.
I did try to use the full path to the file AND just "1.txt" none of which that worked.

This is the code with the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct instructions
{
    unsigned int xd;
    int head;
    string tape;
    string stateCurr;
    char  symbCurr;
    char  symbNew;
    char  direction;
    string stateNew;
};

struct instrPack
{
    instructions instr[1000];

};

ifstream file;
void readInstr(instrPack A[], int &xd);
void useInstrAndHead(instrPack A[], int xd);


int main()
{
    int head, xd;
    string tape;

    instrPack lul[4];
    cout << lul[1].instr[1].symbCurr;

    //cout << "Head: " << head << endl;
    readInstr(lul, xd);
    useInstrAndHead(lul, xd);
    return 0;
}


void readInstr(instrPack lul[], int &xd)
{
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {

        string fileNum;//, fileNum2, fileNum3, fileNum4;
        fileNum = """" + fileNum + ".txt""";;
        file.open("C:\\Users\\clearless\\Desktop\\1.txt");

        if (file.fail()) {
            cerr << "ERROR" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        lul[i].instr[0].xd = 0;
        ifstream fd("C:\\Users\\clearless\\Desktop\\1.txt");
        fd >> lul[i].instr[0].head;
        fd >> lul[i].instr[0].tape;
        //cout << "Tape: |" << tape << "|" << endl;
        while (!fd.eof()) {
            fd >> lul[i].instr[lul[i].instr[0].xd].stateCurr;
            fd >> lul[i].instr[lul[i].instr[0].xd].symbCurr;
            fd >> lul[i].instr[lul[i].instr[0].xd].symbNew;
            fd >> lul[i].instr[lul[i].instr[0].xd].direction;
            fd >> lul[i].instr[lul[i].instr[0].xd].stateNew;
            lul[i].instr[0].xd++;
        }
        //fileNumK++;
    }
    /*
    cout << "Instructions: " << endl << "----------" << endl;
    for (int i=0;i<xd;i++)
    {
        cout <<instr[i].stateCurr << " " << instr[i].symbCurr << " " << instr[i].symbNew << " " <<instr[i].direction << " " <<instr[i].stateNew << endl;
    }
    */


    cout << "----------" << endl;
}

void useInstrAndHead(instrPack lul[], int xd)
{
    for(int k=0; k<4; k++) {
        int breakIt = 0;
        string size = lul[k].instr[0].tape;
        string stateInit = "0";
        while ((lul[k].instr[0].head > 0) || (lul[k].instr[0].head <= size.length()) || (stateInit != "X")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lul[i].instr[0].xd; i++)
            {
                if ((lul[k].instr[0].tape[lul[k].instr[0].head] == lul[k].instr[i].symbCurr) &&
                    (stateInit == lul[k].instr[i].stateCurr))
                {
                    lul[k].instr[0].tape[lul[k].instr[0].head] = lul[k].instr[i].symbNew;

                    if (lul[k].instr[i].direction == 'R')
                    {
                        lul[k].instr[0].head++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lul[k].instr[0].head--;
                    }
                    stateInit = lul[k].instr[i].stateNew;
                    cout << lul[k].instr[0].tape << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code, that works and is quite simillar (basically, the code above was made from the one below):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct instructions
{
  string stateCurr;
  char  symbCurr; 
  char  symbNew; 
  char  direction; 
  string stateNew; 
};

        ifstream file;
void readInstr(int &head, string &tape, instructions A[], int &xd);
void useInstrAndHead(int head, string tape, instructions A[], int xd);


int main()
{
        int head, xd;
        string tape;

        instructions instr[1000];


        cout << "Head: " << head << endl;
        readInstr(head, tape, instr, xd);
        useInstrAndHead(head, tape, instr, xd);
        return 0;
}


void readInstr(int &head, string &tape, instructions instr[], int &xd)
{
        string fileNum;
        cin >> fileNum;
        fileNum = """" + fileNum + ".txt"""; 
        file.open(fileNum);
        if (file.fail())
        {
                cerr << "ERROR" << endl;
                exit(1);
        }
  xd=0;
  ifstream fd(fileNum);
    fd >> head;
    fd >> tape;
            cout << "Tape: |" << tape<< "|" << endl;
    while(!fd.eof())
      {
         fd >> instr[xd].stateCurr;
         fd >> instr[xd].symbCurr;
         fd >> instr[xd].symbNew;
         fd >> instr[xd].direction;
         fd >> instr[xd].stateNew;
     xd++;
      }
    cout << "Instructions: " << endl << "----------" << endl;
    for (int i=0;i<xd;i++)
       {
           cout <<instr[i].stateCurr << " " << instr[i].symbCurr << " " << instr[i].symbNew << " " <<instr[i].direction << " " <<instr[i].stateNew << endl;
       } 


     cout << "----------" << endl;
}

void useInstrAndHead(int head, string tape, instructions instr[], int xd)
{
        int breakIt = 0;
        string size = tape;
        string stateInit = "0"; 
        while((head>0) || (head<=size.length()) || (stateInit!="X"))
        {
         for(int i=0; i<xd; i++)
         {
                  if((tape[head] == instr[i].symbCurr) && (stateInit == instr[i].stateCurr))
                  {
                tape[head] = instr[i].symbNew;

                          if(instr[i].direction == 'R')
                {
                        head++;
                }
                          else
                {
                        head--;
                }


                    stateInit = instr[i].stateNew;
                    cout << tape << endl;
                   }
                  }
        }
}
```

EDIT: First sentence was grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a bit of rush. Edited. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Do you know what `""""`means in C++? Two empty string constants concatenated - making again an empty string. Escaping a `"` in C++ is: `"\""`. If you need two (as due to weird Microsoft thingies) you have to `"\"\""`.

Comment: Regarding my above comment, I saw this in `readInstr()`: `fileNum = """" + fileNum + ".txt""";`. Btw. you don't need the quotes in `std::ifstream::open()`. Instead, if you insert quotes, they might be considered as part of file name what is probably not intended in your case.

Comment: It just gives me an error if do not include the quotes. Either way, that doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: What does this have to do with CLion? Also, please include the actual error you are getting rather than just saying you get "an error"; this is not helpful.

Comment: Concerning the quotes: A string constant has to be quoted in C++, in general. Thus, `"C:\\Users\\clearless\\Desktop\\1.txt"` is a _correct_ C++ string constant whereby occurrences of backslash (\\) are _correctly_ escaped as `"\\"`. This is nothing specific about `std::ifstream`. Please, notice that my comment addresses the occurrence of `""""` and `".txt"""` which _look like_ you had a certain intention but in that case the wrong implementation.